# Java's checkstyle, MagicNumberCheck

Tags: checkstyle, magic-numbers

I am using [*checkstyle*](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) to get reportings about my source-code. This question is about the [*MagicNumberCheck*](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html).

I am using `Date/(org.joda.)DateTime` in my source code like this:

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(2013, 2, 27, 23, 0):
dateTime.plusHours(57);
```

Is there a way to suppress the *MagicNumberCheck notifications* if the magic number is within a Date or DateTime?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use **SuppressionCommentFilter** check to do this.

Configure the properties values like (in your [checkstyle configuration](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html) file)

```
<module name="SuppressionCommentFilter">
  <property name="offCommentFormat" value="Check\:OFF\: ([\w\|]+)"/>
  <property name="onCommentFormat" value="Check\:ON\: ([\w\|]+)"/>
  <property name="checkFormat" value="$1"/>
</module>
```

Now for the required lines, you can do like

```
//Check:OFF: MagicNumber
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(2013, 2, 27, 23, 0):
dateTime.plusHours(57);
//Check:ON: MagicNumber
```

This will only suppress `MagicNumber checks`, the rest checks will work here.

You can suppress Multiple checcks too, like

```
//Check:OFF: MagicNumber|Indentation
Code Here
//Check:ON: MagicNumber|Indentation
```

this will suppress only `MagicNumber and Indentation Checks`. Other checks will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can supress CheckStyle notifications by using the comment

```
//CHECKSTYLE:OFF
```

before those lines and

```
//CHECKSTYLE:ON
```

afterwards to reenable it.

This requires the module **SuppressionCommentFilter** to be enabled.

Of course you could also create your own module that does exactly what you want.

Comment: Hmm, a solutions, but not the solution I have in mind. Contra: - I have to do it every time - this solution suppresses other warnings, too.